# Get Image Vertices for Box2D?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, shapes, vertex

I am trying to get the vertices for an image I have in my app. Currently I have been using Vertex Helper but I want to make my vertex shape a bit wider. However, I am not sure how do this with hard coded values.

I have tried to use Physics Editor but it just outputs a plist which I don't think I can use with the iOS Cocos2D. Anyway what program can I use to get the exact shape I'm looking for and getting the values for that shape for Box2D?

Also just to provide a little more context this is an example of the initialization of a vertex shape that I am talking about:

```
b2Vec2 verts[] = {
            b2Vec2(-25.6f / PTM_RATIO, 50.7f / PTM_RATIO),
            b2Vec2(-20.6f / PTM_RATIO, -48.0f / PTM_RATIO),
            b2Vec2(27.3f / PTM_RATIO, -48.0f / PTM_RATIO),
            b2Vec2(21.5f / PTM_RATIO, 51.5f / PTM_RATIO),
            b2Vec2(-26.8f / PTM_RATIO, 49.8f / PTM_RATIO) };
        spriteShape.Set(verts, num);
```

Any advice, tips, or ideas would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Consult the PhysicsEditor documentation. Of course you can use it with cocos2d-iphone. You need to use the GBShapeCache class provided in the PE installer DMG. Once you get past that, you'll ask yourself how you could have ever worked with VertexHelper. ;)

Comment: That's great to hear! One question though, Since I scale my image to be either bigger or smaller, is it possible to also scale the shape from the plist to match the size of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go ahead and use PhysicsEditor with the GB2ShapeCache files. I am going to have to do some subclassing and modification though of the class because it is not natively made to work with b2ContactListeners I guess. Anyway can correct me if I am wrong though.